# Application not auto creating AccountController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-templates

I am creating an MVC project in **VS2017** and in **VS2015**, when you create an MVC templated ASP.NET Web App, it will automatically build an account controller for you which adds register and log in functionality. It will add an **AccountController.cs** and **ManageController.cs** to controllers with the appropriate views.

But in **VS2017**, when I create an MVC project it doesn't add this to the project. I've tried importing the files from an old **VS2015** project, but It didn't seem to work. How can I get around this? Is there a way to create a project with the account controller or did they remove that in **VS2017**?

Comment: I just created an MVC application and the "individual accounts" option for authentication and the `AccountController` file is there. Did you select some form of authentication when you created the app?

Comment: That was exactly my problem, I wasn't changing the authentication so there was none selected. I made a new project with "individual accounts" selected and the account controller is created. Thanks for pointing that out for me, my issue is now resolved!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to select some form of authentication when you create the app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My issue/resolution was slightly different than the accepted answer.  I was choosing the "Web API" template while checking the "MVC" checkbox and I DID select Individual User Accounts, but the account controller/views were still not created.  It appears the Account boilerplate doesn't get generated with the Web API option, regardless of what you choose for Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem myself today creating an ASP.NET Core Web Application with identity. changing the version from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to ASP.NET Core 2.0 fixed the problem.
I am using visual studio version 15.7.6, .NET Framework version 4.7.03056

Answer (score 1):

You can easily execute this command in the nuget console and your problem will be solved:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Version 2.2.0-alpha1
```